# Integration - Constant of integration when exponentials or logs are involved.

Tags: integration

When integrating something I understand that you get left with +C but in some cases when Logs of Exponentials are involved i have seen in solutions that people turn the + C in LnK or E^k sometimes. How do I know when to do this? For example in the question below the solution has an A in there. Where did this come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'A' came in the picture as they had to remove the $ln$, try taking the $\ln$ of $$N=Ae^{-t/3}$$, you get $$\ln N= \frac{-t}{3}+ \ln A$$ And by expressing the 'C' in the previous step as $\ln A$,(This can be done as both are constants) They conveniently removed the $\ln$ from both sides altogether.

Comment: How do you identify when to turn the constant into a Ln(A) as that is where I am struggling in these questions. 

Also why can I turn it into A because it's a constant? What do you mean by this. Thanks @Nikunj

Comment: You can turn the constant into an ln function when you want to get rid of an existing ln (may sound confusing!)  as an example, in your original problem we had ln N on the L.H.S, so , to get rid of ln N, and simply write it as N, we put ln A, also note that there would have been NO problem if we used C, the expression would then become $$N=e^{c}e^{-t/3}$$ as you see we put C= ln A, it became a much better expression, as $$e^{ln A}=A$$, so this is just for convenience and you can check that the final answer doesn't depend on it.

Comment: So N=ece−t/3 is actually equivalent to the answer with A? @Nikunj Also why is LnA and C the same? also is there any situation where I should think of making C => E^C or should I only look at turning C to lnA. Thanks.

Comment: 1.Yes,2.because we chose A in such a manner that ln A =C, 3. Depends if it can make the problem easier/representation simpler then yes

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answers.